# Is there a way to tell what physical machine a Linux program is running in?

Tags: linux, hardware

I want to be able to detect the specific model of server from a running program (I.e a Dell vostro 470).

Is there a robust method to determine this from a running program in Linux?

Comment: Does `sudo dmidecode -s 'system-product-name'` show what you want? Btw I'm not sure what you mean with *"determine this from a running program in Linux"*. What programming language does your program use? Can you edit its source code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If your Linux is running directly in a computer (on bare metal), it is easy for example with dmidecode or lshw, but if your Linux is running in a virtual machine (for example in Virtualbox), it might be harder because there is a layer between your Linux and the computer.

Comment: The program is written in Go, and I am able to edit the source code. I assumed the solution would be source code agnostic, but if there is a particularly clean way to do this in Go I would love to know.

So the program may be running on baremetal directly, or ontop of a virtual machine. It would have to be a solution that would work in either case,

Comment: @user21113865 In the case Linux is running in virtual machine, as sudodus said, it should be harder to find the system information. But you can run the command  `dmidecode` or `lshw` via ssh in your host/bare metal machine, but this one should be a Linux system too (not sure about macOS) but if the bare metal system is WIndows then you should use another command (which I do not know it, since I know nothing about Windows )